# Debugging a core dump of an unmanaged crash occurring within a dotnet application running in a Linux container

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, native, coredump

We are running a Kubernetes cluster with various services. If one of them crashes, we get a core dump. But so far it has resisted all attempts at debugging.
It's likely due to it being a dotnet application running under Linux with the crash happening inside a native memory dependency.
I have built the dependency with debug symbols in VSCode.

I tried opening the core dump with gdb within the container using the net7.0/Debug version of the dll. I tried the dotnet executable. I tried various other files but to no avail.

I also tried debugging with Visual Studio but all threads are unlabeled/type unknown and the callstack only contains [Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code].
Under [Modules] I can see the debug symbols for the crashing dependency are loaded.

What do I have to do to get the stacktrace to show up correctly?